# JavaScript anti-flood spam protection?

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention

I was wondering if it were possible to implement some kind of crude JavaScript anti-flood protection.
My code receives events from a server through AJAX, but sometimes these events can be quite frequent (they're not governed by me).

I have attempted to come up with a method of combating this, and I've written a small script: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry5k9/

```
var puts = {};

function receiverFunction(id, text) {
       if ( !puts[id] ) {
           puts = {};
           puts[id] = {};
       }

       puts[id].start = puts[id].start || new Date();
       var count = puts[id].count = puts[id].count + 1 || 0;
       var time = (new Date() - puts[id].start) * 0.001;

       $("text").set("text", (count / time.toFixed()).toString() + " lines/second");

       doSomethingWithTextIfNotSpam(text);
   }
};
```

which I think could prove effective against these kinds of attacks, but I'm wondering if it can be improved or perhaps rewritten?

So far, I think everything more than 3 or 2.5 lines per second seems like spam, but as time progresses forward (because start mark was set... well... at the start), an offender could simply idle for a while and then commence the flood, effectively never passing 1 line per minute.

Also, I would like to add that I use Mootools and Lo-Dash libraries (maybe they provide some interesting methods), but it would be preferable if this can be done using native JS.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's likely that if someone spams the site they're not using a browser to do it (i.e. they're bypassing JavaScript completely). And in any case if anyone copy-pastes text to the input field your method either breaks down or thinks they're trying to flood the site.

Comment: @Juhana: But I'm receiving events from the server (which I cannot control).

Comment: Then I don't really understand what you're trying to do, sorry. If the events are coming from the server, what is the keydown event trying to capture?

Comment: I used keydown just to demonstrate what I meant, it could be a simple function (it's actually Mootools' onSuccess function). Perhaps I wasn't clear on it though and should change it.

Comment: If you're using AJAX, you're REQUESTING events, not receiving them. What flood are you talking about?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: It's a Comet model, server pushes events to the browser, essentially XMLHttpRequest long polling.

Comment: @VariousThings, in such case I'd recommend doing some lightweight aggregation of incoming data and while performing heavy tasks (e.g. UI redraw) only at some specific threshold, using previously aggregated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent many days pondering on effective measures to forbid message-flooding, until I came across the solution implemented somewhere else.

First, we need three things, penalty and score variables, and a point in time where last action occured:

```
var score = 0;
var penalty = 200; // Penalty can be fine-tuned.
var lastact = new Date();
```

Next, we decrease score by the distance between the previous message and current in time.

```
/* The smaller the distance, more time has to pass in order
 * to negate the score penalty cause{d,s}.
 */
score -= (new Date() - lastact) * 0.05; 

// Score shouldn't be less than zero.
score = (score < 0) ? 0 : score;
```

Then we add the message penalty and check if it crosses the threshold:

```
if ( (score += penalty) > 1000 ) {
   // Do things.
}
```

Shouldn't forget to update last action afterwards:

```
lastact = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the frequency a particular javascript function fires, you could [`debounce`](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) the function.

In your example, I guess it would be something like:

```
onSuccess: function(){ _.debounce(someOtherFunction, timeOut)};
```

where `timeout` is the maximum frequency you want `someOtherFunction` to be called.

Comment: `onSuccess` function I use is quite complex and depends on returned outputs of each individual function (event types, something like "connected", "disconnected" etc.). Checking the source code, it seems that debouncing it would return "the result of the last func call" which might break already fragile code.

Comment: "Already fragile code"? - sounds like it's refactoring time... :)

Comment: @ma_il: Haha, maybe. I'd have to reinvent everything and "if it works, don't fix it" kinda applies here.

Comment: ah fair enough, you could potentially debounce each event by type separately?

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about native JavaScript, but maybe take a look at [RxJS](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/RxJS/).

> RxJS or Reactive Extensions for JavaScript is a library for
>   transforming, composing, and querying streams of data. We mean all
>   kinds of data too, from simple arrays of values, to series of events
>   (unfortunate or otherwise), to complex flows of data.

There is an example on that page which uses the `throttle` method to "Ignores values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value before dueTime" (see [source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/rx.time.js)).

```
keyup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup').select(function(ev) {
            return ev.target.value;
        }).where(function(text) {
            return text.length > 2;
        }).throttle(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
```

There might be a similar way to get your 2.5-3 per second and ignore the rest of the events until the next second.